# Applying cleanups in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have enabled several C cleanups for Emacs by setting the c-cleanup-list variable, and then enabling electric and auto-newline modes.  Unfortunately, this only formats the code as you're typing it.  I would like to format code that has already been written.  Is there a quick way to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I employ a simple cleanup function:

```
(defun cleanup-buffer ()
  "Perform a bunch of operations on the whitespace content of a buffer."
  (interactive)
  (indent-buffer)
  (untabify-buffer)
  (delete-trailing-whitespace))
```

that I've assigned a global keybinding to:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'cleanup-buffer)
```

You can put your cleanups in a similar function and invoke it instead. You can also make Emacs trigger such a function on buffer save(or some other event) - have a look at the **after-save-hook**.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It just feels like someone would have put all these cleanups into one big lisp file....